# I need to Implement the following code segment in the ARC assembly language

Tags: if-statement, assembly, architecture, arc-architecture

```
if  x <= y:
    y = y + 1
else if x != z
    y = y-1
else
    z = z + 1
```

This is what i have for my Arc assembly code. Im fairly new at this so im not too sure how to make the if/else statement into assembly code.

```
! This program executes an If/else statement
    .begin
    .org 2048
prog1:  ld  [X], %r1    ! this loads memory X into register 1 
        ld  [Y], %r2    ! this loads memory y into register 2


X:  0
Y:  0
Z:  0
    .end
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to perform comparison is the subtract instruction (the version that update the flags, i.e. `subcc`).
You can specify `%r0` as destination operand since the result of such subtraction is not needed (taking advantage of the ARC three operands form).

Suppose you do this

```
subcc %r1, %r2, %r0
```

The following are true

- The result is discarded as it is written in `r0`
- If the `C` flag is set then `r2 > r1`
- If the `C` flag is not set then `r2 <= r1`
- If the `Z` flag is set then `r2 == r1`
- If the `Z` flag is not set then `r2 !=r1`

**I have never written ARC assembly code**. Here is an attempt to translate the given code, **I cannot debug or even assemble this code**. So consider it as a concise way to explain the concept above.

```
! This program executes an If/else statement
    .begin
    .org 2048
prog1:  ld  [X], %r1        ! this loads memory X into register 1 
        ld  [Y], %r2        ! this loads memory y into register 2
    ld  [Z], %r3        ! this loads memory z into register 3

    subcc %r2, %r1, %r0 !y ? x
    bcs .else_if        ;x > y

    add %r2, 1, %r2     !y = y + 1
    ba .end

.else_if:
    subcc %r1, %r3, $r0 ;x ? z 
    beq .else       ;x == z

    sub %r2, 1, %r2
    ba .end

.else:
    add %r3, 1, %r3     !z = z + 1
    ba .end

X:  0
Y:  0
Z:  0
    .end
```

Indeed I hope this is not a working version since it will at least force you into some thinking-learning process in the attempt to correct it :)